# Create a Robinson world map with grid and coordinate frame in QGIS Map Composer?

Tags: qgis, grids-graticules

I am trying to create a world map in Robinson projection (ESRI:54030) from the Wikimedia World Map, using QGIS Map Composer. It should have a grid (spacing about 20°, not too bold/aggressive) and a zebra-style coordinate frame and look approximately like this (regarding number and boldness of lines and rounded sides): [image: Example]

If I follow the QGIS/MapComposer tutorials you can find online, the only thing I manage to achieve, however, is this: [image]

You see: The coordinates at the frame are nonsense, the corners are not rounded, and the grid lines are hard-coded to 5cm or so, as "Map unit" didn't work. I'd rather have the grid lines follow the meridians and circles of latitude with something like a 20, 40 or 60° spacing. Also, the grid lines seem too bold. But my biggest concern is that the frame doesn't fit to the map but rather leave plenty of margins around the actual map. And though trying many different things, I have not yet found a way to have the actual map fill the map area completely.

Could somebody guide me through the composing process or refer to a good tutorial?

Comment: what projection is your map set to?

Comment: EPSG: 54030, i.e. Robinson projection.

Answer (score 4):

For a non rectangular global projection like Robinson, QGis print composer grids will not be able to follow the cut off's of the globe as you would like. The trick is to include a graticule grid in your map so that it is reprojected for you.

Here I have used 110m_physical_geographic_lines, 110m_graticules_10, 110m_land and 110m_ocean from Natural Earth to show how it looks:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this first hint, which goes into the right direction. However, this doesn't help yet with regard to the frame incl. coordinates, nor with the map margins.

Comment: you would need to add labels to the grid layer