# Adding meridians and parallels on world map in QGIS

Tags: qgis, cartography, mapping, grids-graticules

I'm working on a world map in which I'm using as overlapped layers Bing Aerial, The natural Earth Vector (from natural earth data.com), and also a NASA night view because it's just nice!

I would like to add the standard meridians and parallels, I heard something about grids, but those you have to scale manually. Isn't there somewhere a download link for a layer that adds them? Or alternatively, how should I make them?

---

I found a post on here which could be helpful to understand what I'm looking for:

[Create a Robinson world map with grid and coordinate frame in QGIS Map Composer?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/312463/create-a-robinson-world-map-with-grid-and-coordinate-frame-in-qgis-map-composer)

The last reply to that question refers to a file called 110m_graticules_10 inside the Natural Earth package which I guess is for I was searching (not sure though), although the geographical lines layer is nice the grid showed in the last pic is what I was trying to replicate.

I tried to search for 110m_graticules_10 inside the folder Natural Earth but I could find it.

Answer (score 6):

You could just use

```
<QGIS>|Vector|Research Tools|Create Grid...
```

where you

- chose your `Grid type` (likely *Line*)
- set the `Grid CRS` (i.e. to *EPSG:4326 - WGS 84*)
- set the spacing you want in *degree*

and hit *Run*.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! 

I already experimented with it but I would like to have a grid to be set specifically with the standard measurements for the parallels and meridians, and not a made-up grid. I'm honestly surprised it's actually that hard to do such an easy task! Am I the only one who has ever needed those? 

Comment: What do you mean by "I would like to have a grid to be set specifically with the standard measurements for the parallels and meridians, and not a made-up grid."? If you use `Line` as type, `-180,180,-90,90 [EPSG:4326]` as extent, `15` as spacing and `4326` as crs it is pretty standard, isnt it?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds as if you are looking for the [Natural Earth Geographic Lines layer](https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-physical-vectors/10m-geographic-lines/)

> Tropical circles, Polar circles, International dateline, and Equator. Same as 50 million geographic lines.

[image]

Comment: on here https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/312463/create-a-robinson-world-map-with-grid-and-coordinate-frame-in-qgis-map-composer they talk about a  file called 110m_graticules_10 but I could find it inside the Natural Earth package 

Comment: The names change over time, look for graticules somewhere in the name.

Comment: see https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-physical-vectors/10m-graticules/ or https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/110m-physical-vectors/110m-graticules/

Answer (score 1):

The UC Berkeley library provides spatial data files with different latitude and longitude grids on them. Looks like they were originally produced by the North American Cartographic Information Society.

https://geodata.lib.berkeley.edu/?f%5Bdc_format_s%5D%5B%5D=Shapefile&f%5Bdc_publisher_s%5D%5B%5D=North+American+Cartographic+Information+Society&f%5Blayer_geom_type_s%5D%5B%5D=Line

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to download anything, you can add a grid of meridians and parallels labeled with coordinates and customize it any way you want directly in QGIS on Print Layout > Item Properties > Grids.
For more information watch [this video](https://youtu.be/c4q_w9hAknI).